# C++ If then else conditional being skipped

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for class. It takes a sentence and translates it into pseudo japanese (uses english words but rearranges into grammatical order and adds suffixes to pertinent words).

The library is limited and we cannot use functions or arrays (low level class). In THIS case I enter the sentence:

"is man red"  (without the quotes)

The program parses the words correctly. I.e. no spaces around each word.

Here is my code

```
if (word1 == "is")
{
    question = "is-ka";

    //If the second word is a subject, assign it and continue
    //assigning the 3rd or 4th word as the object or adjective and kick out
    //an error if not
    if (word2 == string("man") || word2 == string("woman") || word2 == string("fish"))
    {
        subject = word2 + "-ga";

        if (word3 == "man" || word3 == "woman" || word3 == "fish")
        {
            object = word3 + "-o";
            sentence = subject + ' ' + object + ' ' + question;
            cout << sentence << endl;
        }
        if (word3 == "red" || word3 == "short" || word3 == "strong")
        {
            adj = word3;
            sentence = subject + ' ' + adj + ' ' + question;
            cout << sentence << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "This is not a proper Eng-- sentence." << endl;
            cout << "2 The sentence lacks a proper object." << endl;
        }
    }
```

I test if the first word is 'is' because that is the only question format we are given to use. Given it is a question I proceed to find the subject, object, and adjective that must be in the sentence for it to be grammatically correct.

The first and second conditional for "is man red" pass, but
when the conditional for "is man red" tests if the third word is "red", it skips to the else statement and displays the error.

Why is the conditional skipping when it should be true?

Example of a run:

```
Enter an Eng-- sentence you would like to translate
is man red 

These are the words collected
Spaces after the colons and period at end of word are added.
First word: is.
Second word: man.
Third word: red.

This is not a proper Eng-- sentence.
2 The sentence lacks a proper object.
```

I hope THIS is what you have all been actually asking for. Full code and compiled with input from above

http://ideone.com/qPgM14

Comment: How are the variables declared?

Comment: They are declared as strings

Comment: Please provide a self-contained compiling example with the sample inputs, otherwise how can we debug it easily?

Comment: I provided the example output of what I get. I include woman and fish because those are possible nouns in the spec's library

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/0rWKgw

Comment: That is what is weird, I input the strings into the variable within the if then else blocks and it worked. I thought maybe my parser was not working, but you can see in the example output that it parsed correctly, I also tested if the first and second if statements worked and they did. I have no clue why the third one doesn't when working off the parsed variable assignment

Comment: Please do as @NeilKirk asks and give us a [fully self-contained program](/help/mcve). We want to see your variable declarations. Don't describe them in English; show us the code.

Comment: @John Kugelman I believe I added what you requested this time at the end of the OP. If not I apologize, I'm just not familiar with that is meant by self-contained.

Comment: Think about using a vector and a loop instead of all those numbered variables.

Comment: I would if I were allowed to. As per instructions of our class we can only use what has been taught to us so far and thing slike vectors haven't been touched on.

Comment: Did you click [the link in my comment](/help/mcve)? It describes in further detail what it means to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE)](/help/mcve). Reducing your program down to a smaller one which has the same bug isn't just for our benefit. It also helps you. It's a great way to debug. Cut out irrelevant code, focus on the problematic code. Often the very act of creating an MCVE will help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Ah sorry I did not see that. I am at work at the moment. I will do just that when I get home. Apologies, and thanks.

Comment: In the meantime, have you compared your program to @Barmar's? He "filled in the blanks" so to speak and came up with a working program. So what's different between your version and his?

Comment: Actually, @MikeDinsdale found my problem. He posted it below. I appreciate the time you put into the help, though John. I'll have to check out that link tonight and practice shortening code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `word3` doesn't contain exactly what it seems to, in a particularly confusing way.  The code which reads into it looks like this

```
//Word 3
   while(userSent[index] != ' ' && index <= sentLength)
    {
        word3 += userSent[index];
        index++;
    }
```

The condition `index <= sentLength` should be `index < sentLength` because of the zero-based indexing of C++ strings.  With the `<=` the loop body is also appending the terminating zero byte from `userSent` to `word3`. You can see this is happening by checking `word3.length()`. The extra 0 byte has no effect when printing the string using `cout`'s `operator<<` but it does prevent the string comparing equal with `"red"`.

Comment: Mike, you filthy freakin genius.